# LAN only for specific switchport

Tags: switch, lan

I'm only provided with one switch port so to provide Internet to two PCs they go into a small managed netgear switch.

However I want to add another PC to be able to communicate with the other PCs but must not have Internet connection so LAN only. By default it gets Internet connection.

What do I need to do to make this LAN only.

Comment: Are you assigning the ip addresses statically? You should be able to deny any internet bound traffic from that computer's ip if it remains static

Comment: What make/model is the switch?

Comment: This sounds like a question of an end user of the network and as such is off topic.  If you need additional computers on your switchport, you should talk to those responsible for running your network.

Answer (score 1):

simplest way is to remove the gateway. Without Gateway there is no way out of the subnet.